# How to write Fable bindings for React component library

Tags: f#, fable-f#

Is there any step-by-step guidance available on how to write bindings for a react component library from F#/Fable?

The only example I could find is [fable-react-toolbox](https://github.com/Prolucid/fable-react-toolbox) which makes extensive use of the deprecated `KeyValueList` attribute.

I am particularly interested in using the [BlueprintJS library](http://blueprintjs.com/); I have been able to use `ts2fable` to generate interface corresponding to the various `props` defined but have no idea what to do next or where to ask for help!

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Michael

Comment: have you tried the [Fable Gitter](https://gitter.im/fable-compiler/Fable)?

Answer (score 4):

If you already have the props as interfaces you can use the Fable React Helpers to create your component for you.

Let's assume you want to create a wrapper for the Foo component (you already extracted the props to an interface and called it IFooProps) from the react-bar module the code you write would look something like this.

```
let Foo : ComponentClass<obj> = import "Foo" "react-bar"
let inline foo (props : IFooProps list) elems =
    Fable.Helpers.React.from Foo (keyValueList CaseRules.LowerFirst props) elems
```

The `ComponentClass` type can be found in the `Fable.Import.React` module.

A helpful discussion regarding this topic can be found in this GitHub issue https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable/issues/1044.